# In laravel project with many to many relation, should I put the "value of attribute" in which table of database?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship, relation

I have a laravel project with many to many relation and multi language.
I used [Laravel-Translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) package for multi language. 
This program stores a large number of files with their attributes.
**Each attribute is shared between several files. But each attribute has a different value in each file.** 
Table and their relationship is like this photo: [tables diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g87ac.jpg) 
[image]
should I put the `attribute_value` in which table??
thank you

Comment: if you need to translate the value then add it to the attibute_trans table else put it in the attribute table

Comment: @madalinivascu thank you. I need to translate the value of attribute. should I put the attribute_value in which table?

Comment: @madalinivascu each attribute has a different value in each file for this reason, the value of the attribute can not be in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `attribute_value` to the `attrib_file` table. Because for each connection with a file `attribute_value` should be different. On the other hand, each file stores number of attribute values. That's why `attrib_file` pivot table fits best.
How to retrieve information from pivot table is given in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
$attr = App\Attribute::find(1);
foreach($attr->files as $file) {
  echo $file->pivot->attribute_value;
}
```

Make sure to add `->withPivot('attribute_value')` end of return `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\File')` in your relation method. It should be something like this within the **Attribute** model:

```
..
public function files() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\File')->withPivot('attribute_value');
}
```

Comment: thank you. Do you mean to put it in the pivot table (attrib_file)?
 if yes, how to read attribute_value from pivot? What code?

Comment: I added it to my answer. Check it, please.

Comment: thank you. but when I use `var_dump($file->pivot);`  I get only: `{"attribute_id":1,"file_id":1}`. but I need to `attribute_value` that is in the table but not show!!

Comment: I add `->withPivot('attribute_value')` end of  `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\File')` and work fine! please add this to your answer.
thank you.